# YARN unable to use embedded HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop-yarn, apache-zookeeper

My installation has YARN running with Kerberos and SSL enabled in a small sandbox HDP 3.1 cluster. YARN ATS is running in embedded mode.

The problem is that YARN is not able to come up because the HBase connectors are getting stuck while trying to read the base znode at /atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid.

If I delete the base znode, the Resource Manager is able to come up; however, the znode is eventually created by the embedded HBase Master and the Timeline Reader v2 gets stuck while trying to read it. The same case occurs with the Node Managers.

There are no ERRORs in the logs form any of the services, the last message I get before it gets stuck is:

```
2019-02-27 16:24:10,321 INFO  common.HBaseTimelineStorageUtils (HBaseTimelineStorageUtils.java:getTimelineServiceHBaseConf(65)) - Using hbase configuration at file:///usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager/conf/embedded-yarn-ats-hbase/hbase-site.xml
2019-02-27 16:24:10,446 INFO  zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient (ReadOnlyZKClient.java:<init>(130)) - Start read only zookeeper connection 0x1bbae752 to master01.dom.lab:2181,hive01.dom.lab:2181,master02.dom.lab:2181, session timeout 90000 ms, retries 6, retry interval 1000 ms, keep alive 60000 ms
2019-02-27 16:24:10,454 INFO  zookeeper.ZooKeeper (ZooKeeper.java:<init>(438)) - Initiating client connection, connectString=master01.dom.lab:2181,hive01.dom.lab:2181,master02.dom.lab:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient$$Lambda$15/700988999@6ccab51a
2019-02-27 16:24:10,456 INFO  client.ZooKeeperSaslClient (ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:run(289)) - Client will use GSSAPI as SASL mechanism.
2019-02-27 16:24:10,456 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient (ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:run(291)) - creating sasl client: client=rm/master02.dom.lab@DOM.LAB;service=zookeeper;serviceHostname=hive01.dom.lab
2019-02-27 16:24:10,457 INFO  zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:logStartConnect(1019)) - Opening socket connection to server hive01.dom.lab/10.14.19.29:2181. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client'
2019-02-27 16:24:10,457 INFO  zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:primeConnection(864)) - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /10.14.19.25:39414, server: hive01.dom.lab/10.14.19.29:2181
2019-02-27 16:24:10,458 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:primeConnection(936)) - Session establishment request sent on hive01.dom.lab/10.14.19.29:2181
2019-02-27 16:24:10,461 INFO  zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:onConnected(1279)) - Session establishment complete on server hive01.dom.lab/10.14.19.29:2181, sessionid = 0x1692b5629cb0012, negotiated timeout = 60000
2019-02-27 16:24:10,462 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient (ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:sendSaslPacket(421)) - ClientCnxn:sendSaslPacket:length=0
2019-02-27 16:24:10,462 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient (ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:run(369)) - saslClient.evaluateChallenge(len=0)
2019-02-27 16:24:10,470 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO (ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:findSendablePacket(184)) - deferring non-priming packet: clientPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid serverPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid finished:false header:: 0,4  replyHeader:: 0,0,0  request:: '/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid,F  response::  until SASL authentication completes.
2019-02-27 16:24:10,473 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO (ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:findSendablePacket(184)) - deferring non-priming packet: clientPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid serverPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid finished:false header:: 0,4  replyHeader:: 0,0,0  request:: '/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid,F  response::  until SASL authentication completes.
2019-02-27 16:24:10,473 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient (ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:run(369)) - saslClient.evaluateChallenge(len=50)
2019-02-27 16:24:10,474 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient (ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:sendSaslPacket(403)) - ClientCnxn:sendSaslPacket:length=86
2019-02-27 16:24:10,475 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO (ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:findSendablePacket(184)) - deferring non-priming packet: clientPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid serverPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid finished:false header:: 0,4  replyHeader:: 0,0,0  request:: '/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid,F  response::  until SASL authentication completes.
2019-02-27 16:24:10,475 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO (ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:findSendablePacket(184)) - deferring non-priming packet: clientPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid serverPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid finished:false header:: 0,4  replyHeader:: 0,0,0  request:: '/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid,F  response::  until SASL authentication completes.
2019-02-27 16:24:10,475 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO (ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:findSendablePacket(184)) - deferring non-priming packet: clientPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid serverPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid finished:false header:: 0,4  replyHeader:: 0,0,0  request:: '/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid,F  response::  until SASL authentication completes.
2019-02-27 16:24:10,475 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO (ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:findSendablePacket(184)) - deferring non-priming packet: clientPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid serverPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid finished:false header:: 0,4  replyHeader:: 0,0,0  request:: '/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid,F  response::  until SASL authentication completes.
2019-02-27 16:24:10,476 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO (ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:findSendablePacket(184)) - deferring non-priming packet: clientPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid serverPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid finished:false header:: 0,4  replyHeader:: 0,0,0  request:: '/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid,F  response::  until SASL authentication completes.
2019-02-27 16:24:10,476 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO (ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:findSendablePacket(184)) - deferring non-priming packet: clientPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid serverPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid finished:false header:: 0,4  replyHeader:: 0,0,0  request:: '/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid,F  response::  until SASL authentication completes.
2019-02-27 16:24:10,476 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO (ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:findSendablePacket(184)) - deferring non-priming packet: clientPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid serverPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid finished:false header:: 0,4  replyHeader:: 0,0,0  request:: '/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid,F  response::  until SASL authentication completes.
2019-02-27 16:24:10,477 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:readResponse(830)) - Reading reply sessionid:0x1692b5629cb0012, packet:: clientPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid serverPath:/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid finished:false header:: 3,4  replyHeader:: 3,51539608995,0  request:: '/atsv2-hbase-secure/hbaseid,F  response:: #ffffffff000146d61737465723a3137303030ffffffa676ffffffb9ffffffd013ffffffe7ffffffbe6950425546a2433663031656330342d343039362d343834322d386632302d353236356562616138306161,s{25769804836,51539608796,1550173035842,1551282324524,29,0,30,0,67,0,25769804836} 
2019-02-27 16:24:12,017 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:readResponse(729)) - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2692b567b9b0013 after 0ms
2019-02-27 16:24:13,646 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:readResponse(729)) - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2692b567b9b0014 after 0ms
2019-02-27 16:24:15,353 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:readResponse(729)) - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2692b567b9b0013 after 0ms
2019-02-27 16:24:16,981 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:readResponse(729)) - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2692b567b9b0014 after 0ms
2019-02-27 16:24:18,689 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:readResponse(729)) - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2692b567b9b0013 after 0ms
2019-02-27 16:24:20,317 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:readResponse(729)) - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2692b567b9b0014 after 0ms
2019-02-27 16:24:22,027 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:readResponse(729)) - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2692b567b9b0013 after 0ms
2019-02-27 16:24:23,653 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:readResponse(729)) - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2692b567b9b0014 after 1ms
2019-02-27 16:24:25,365 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:readResponse(729)) - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2692b567b9b0013 after 0ms
2019-02-27 16:24:26,989 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:readResponse(729)) - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2692b567b9b0014 after 0ms
2019-02-27 16:24:28,702 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:readResponse(729)) - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x2692b567b9b0013 after 0ms
```

The ACLs of the znode seem correct:

```
[zk: master01:2181,master02:2181,hive01:2181(CONNECTED) 13] getAcl /atsv2-hbase-secure
'sasl,'yarn
: cdrwa
'world,'anyone
: r
'sasl,'yarn-ats-hbase
: cdrwa
```

Below are some relevant configuration settings from the embedded HBase instance:

hbase-env:

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

hbase-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>zookeeper.recovery.retry</name>
  <value>6</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>zookeeper.session.timeout</name>
  <value>90000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
  <value>/atsv2-hbase-secure</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
  <value>kerberos</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.superuser</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/hadoop/yarn/tmp/hbase-${user.name}</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
  <value>2181</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>master01.dom.lab,hive01.dom.lab,master02.dom.lab</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>/atsv2/hbase/data</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rpc.protection</name>
  <value>authentication</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
  <value>90000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.local.dir</name>
  <value>${hbase.tmp.dir}/local</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here were the permissions set in the JVM tmp directory under the Ambari configuration directories.

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate more about this issue?